# nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate("/usr/local/etc/nginx/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:0A00018F:SSL routines::ee key too small)

Tags: nginx, homebrew

I have installed nginx using the command "brew install nginx" with latest version 1.25.3

Now when I try to run nginx I got the below error,

1. nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "ssl" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:44

**Luckily I have resolved the above error by editing in nginx.conf file
as seen in the screenshot,**

[image]

****After this when I try to run nginx again, I got the below new error, which I could'nt able resolve.**
**

2. nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_certificate("/usr/local/etc/nginx/server.crt") failed (SSL: error:0A00018F:SSL routines::ee key too small)

I request if anyone knows please guide me here how to resolve this error to run nginx successfully.
If you guys know how to download particular nginx verison, please let me know, I will try that too.

Thank you!

I tried by replacing nginx.conf file.
I tried to replace server.key and server.crt files.
I tried to change the nginx version, but I could not able to downgrade or change nginx version from any command.
I tried to uninstall and install nginx again.

Comment: It worked. Thank you